# Set the color for scatter-plot with DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am using python to plot a pandas DataFrame

I set the color for plotting like this:

```
allDf = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[0,1,2,4,7,6],
    'y':[0,3,2,4,5,7],
    'a':[1,1,1,0,0,0],
    'c':['red','green','blue','red','green','blue']
},index = ['p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6'])

allDf.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y',c='c')
plt.show()
```

However it doesn't work (every point has a blue color)

If I changed the definition of DataFrame like this

```
'c':[1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

It appears color but only black and white, I want to use blue, red and more...

Answer (score 2):

Replace it by:

```
allDf.plot(kind='scatter',x='x',y='y',c=allDf.c)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works well, but I thought I should pass the name of lines as  argumens to plot(). like 'x' and 'y' . Why not like allDf.plot(kind='scatter',x=allDf.x, y=allDf.y, c=allDf.c)

Comment: The [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) documentation explains what kind of arguments are allowed. For `x` and `y` it's "label or position" for most other parameters it simply passes them to `matplotlib` (so you can't specify them by "label or position").

Comment: It's understandable mistake, it all come with practice. :D Like MSeifert said below, you are litterally asking him to use the color 'c':cyan : )

Comment: I see it's the specification of plot(). I need to get used to it more.

Answer (score 0):

The `c` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) is in this case passed through **literally** so everything will have the color [`'c'` (cyan)](https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#colors).

You need to pass your column directly:

```
allDf.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', c=allDf['c'])
```

[image]

It's a bit weird and not well documented when the `c` parameter will use the column and when it will use the literal value. So in this case it's probably best to provide the "colors" explicitly. You might want to take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.2/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L792-L853) in case you're interested to debug what is happening there.

Comment: I think the c stand for cyan. :D